# Azure CDN - long response time, not loading sometimes

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am using Azure CDN. However, in the last few days, I have been experiencing some issues.
If I run a request, sometimes the waiting time is above 10s, and sometimes no content is delivered. There are no errors; if I rerun the same request, it finishes with 200 OK.

My request header looks like this:

```
GET <some_path_to_image>/4.png HTTP/2
Host: cdnstatic.<my_domain>.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: cs,sk;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: https://www.<my_domain>.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://www.<my_domain>.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
TE: trailers
```

And the response is:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Sat, 13 Jan 2024 12:20:08 GMT
content-type: image/png
content-length: 4184
last-modified: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 07:52:50 GMT
etag: "5d711053-1168"
cache-control: max-age=14515200, public, proxy-revalidate
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-azure-ref: 20240113T122008Z-<some_id>
x-cache: TCP_HIT
accept-ranges: bytes
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

One time this request did not finish at all (it remained with "**pending status**"), another time response time was over 10s, next time it was finished under 30ms. The headers are every time the same. I have disabled cache in browser.